# Plotting a scatterplot with large rasters in R?

Tags: r, raster, scatter-plot, tiff

I have two [rasters](/questions/tagged/rasters) in [r](/questions/tagged/r)

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(devtools)
library(DGVMTools)
library(Metrics)
library(hydroGOF)
library(sp)
library(grid)
library(latticeExtra)

> Y
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2803, 5303, 14864309  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent     : 60.85, 105.0417, 15.95833, 39.31667  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 0, 26.53035  (min, max)

> X
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2803, 5303, 14864309  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent     : 60.85, 105.0417, 15.95833, 39.31667  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : memory
names      : VegH
values     : 0, 17.99169  (min, max)
```

I am plotting a [scatter-plot](/questions/tagged/scatter-plot) betweeen these two rasters,
`plot(x,Y)`

[image: Scatterplot 1]

However due to so many pixels, a warning comes:

> Warning message: In .local(x, y, ...) :   plot used a sample of 0.7%
> of the cells. You can use "maxpixels" to increase the sample)

After converting both of the rasters to [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) and plotting a [scatter-plot](/questions/tagged/scatter-plot), *it takes approx 1 hour for a scatterplot to appear, and it shows a big black chunck*.
[image]
Reproducible rasters:

```
r1 <- r2 <- raster(nrows=2803, ncols=5303)
values(r1) <- runif(ncell(r1))
values(r2) <- runif(ncell(r2))
```

My question is how can I efficiently plot a scatterplot between two large rasters datasets , that can be also visually diagnosed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With so many cells, a sample should be the way to go if you just wanted to inspect the scatterplot? You can use "maxpixels" to increase the sample (as indicated by the Warning message you got). For example:

```
X <- Y <- raster(nrows=2803, ncols=5303)
values(X) <- 10 * runif(ncell(X))
values(Y) <- values(X) * (runif(ncell(Y)) - 0.5)

plot(X, Y, maxpixels=1e5)
```

But, that, indeed, takes a while.

Perhaps this is a better way to do it --- it also takes a while but allows for better interpretation

```
plot(X, Y, maxpixels=1e5, gridded=TRUE)
```

Comment: How can I know which value to put in the maxpixels? In the code above you mentioned 1e5, Which will be the suitable value for maxpixels?

Comment: That is for you to decide, based on your data and your needs